# REACT Map set key on Article

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a number of articles.
Using React framework.
I am setting the key on the article via the map function
I get the error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop".

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineMinus, AiOutlinePlus } from "react-icons/ai";
const Question = ({ data }) => {
  const [IsPhidden, SetIsPhidden] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <>
            <article key={item.id} className='question'>
              <header>
                <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                <button
                  onClick={() => SetIsPhidden(!IsPhidden)}
                  className='btn'
                >
                  {IsPhidden ? <AiOutlinePlus /> : <AiOutlineMinus />}
                </button>
              </header>
              {!IsPhidden && <p>{item.info} </p>}
            </article>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Question;
```

Comment: make sure your "data" items have unique "id" values, anyway I suggest you use the array index with some string like `article_${index}` as a key value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the direct children of the map is this component: `<>`, not `<article>`. So the "key" prop should be in the React fragment component. Another thing you can do (and that's my suggestion) is to remove that fragment since it's not necessary. Just like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineMinus, AiOutlinePlus } from "react-icons/ai";
const Question = ({ data }) => {
  const [IsPhidden, SetIsPhidden] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <article key={item.id} className='question'>
            <header>
              <h4>{item.title}</h4>
              <button
                onClick={() => SetIsPhidden(!IsPhidden)}
                className='btn'
              >
                {IsPhidden ? <AiOutlinePlus /> : <AiOutlineMinus />}
              </button>
            </header>
            {!IsPhidden && <p>{item.info} </p>}
          </article>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Question;
```